# download audit log for email activities

Tags: email, logging, download, audit

Is there a way to download g suite email audit log (not manually from google admin console) for a big company?
If i'm not wrong the API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit) is limited by 1000 monitors per day?
May be is possible to have a mirror of logs in BigQuery or in any other place readable with no limits?

Thanks, Paolo.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question you have posed and the tags provided leave visitors with a very vague ask.  Each mail server has different features and while some may have exactly the API you are looking for, others may not have any API at all.  If you could, please edit your question to provide some more details into the activities you are looking to analyze and the mail servers the big company is using for their mail; there is usually a mail server for vending mailboxes to users and a different SMTP server for sending mail to other mail servers.

Comment: ok thanks, question edited, I had forgotten to specify that the question was related to google mail :)